# Firebase real time database isn't working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

When I try to add data to firebase database nothing happens

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    reference=database.getReference("comment");
    uploadButton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
     uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {


       reference.setValue("zizo");
     }
 });
```

note:the phone is connected to the internet ,I wrote the user permission to use the internet

Comment: Are you sure no other View blocks ImageButton and onClick fires? Are there any Firebase related logs?

Comment: can it be related to country i created new project enter my country and it worked

Comment: The most common cause would be a problem with the security rules. Check if you're getting a security error by listening for them as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/19721/detect-errors-when-writing-a-value-on-android#t=201706101615462970098

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    DatabaseReference database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("comment");
     uploadButton=(ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
    uploadButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


   reference.setValue("zizo");
 }
 });
```

Comment: Still nothing happens ,my database rules are set to true read and write